# Show the Takagi function is not differentiable at x=1/6

Tags: real-analysis

The Takagi function is defined as f(x) = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f_0(2^nx)}{2^n}$ where $f_0(x)$ is the periodic sawooth function $f_0(x) = min(x-floor(x), 1-(x-floor(x)))$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(1/6)}{x-1/6}$ cannot exist.

I know f(x)=1/2 for all $x_m= 1/2 - \sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{4^n}$ and $x_m$ converges to 1/6, and for the first step of the proof I have to compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x_m)-f(1/6)}{x_m-1/6}$

Can someone please walk me through how to figure out the value of the Takagi function for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at the following: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1691.pdf (page 8, Section 2.1) where one can prove the Takagi function is not differentiable at any point (Billingsley’s proof in the American Mathematical Monthly). As a corollary, one gets that is not differentiable at $x= \frac{1}{6}$.